# Create dataframe in python based on status of dag in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have the 20 dags in airflow and I want to create a dataframe of status of these dags (that means successful, failed or running). The dataframe contains of 2 columns first name of dag second status of dag.
Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: where do you have these 20 dags? saved into variables?

Comment: you can use "dagrun" airflow api

Comment: @NicoCaldo these dags store as dataset.

Comment: @ozs I read the documentation of dagrun but i can't figure out how to use it for this purpose would you please give me more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create script outside airflow that call airflow api.
here is an example that getting all dag and their last run with state

I assumed for simplicity (local server, basic_auth):

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

airflow_server = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/"
auth = HTTPBasicAuth("airflow", "airflow")

get_dags_url = f"{airflow_server}dags"
get_dag_params = {
    "limit": 100,
    "only_active": "true"
}

response = requests.get(get_dags_url, params=get_dag_params, auth=auth)
dags = response.json()["dags"]

get_dag_run_params = {
    "limit": 100,
}
for dag in dags:
    dag_id = dag["dag_id"]
    dag_run_url = f"{airflow_server}/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns?limit=100"
    response = requests.get(dag_run_url, params=get_dag_run_params, auth=auth)
    dag_runs = response.json()["dag_runs"]
    for dag_run in dag_runs:
        print(f"{dag_id=}\t\t{dag_run['start_date']}\t{dag_run['end_date']}\t{dag_run['state']}")
```

Comment: With some changes based on my Curl and dags it works thansk alot. I want to know it is possible to extract that which the task ID that failed ?

Comment: @h.b, use api/v1/dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}/taskInstances?limit=100&state=failed